# how do i show a widget from a diffrent widget?

Tags: python, pyqt5, qwidget

i have two widgets, one of them is a main widget (even though it uses Qwidgets.Qwidget), and the other one is a side widget that is supposed to appear from the main widget.
i tried to use a button, and that onclick, the side widget would show. but instead the app crashes after a sec.

here's the code for the main:

```
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets
import sys

# help is the script of the side widget
import help
class KeyGrabber(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        try:
            super().__init__()
            layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self)
            self.button = QtWidgets.QPushButton('start')
            layout.addWidget(self.button)
            self.button.setCheckable(True)
            self.button.toggled.connect(self.show_widget)
        except Exception as error:
            print(error.__str__())

    def show_widget(self):
        try:
            help.main(sys.argv)
        except Exception as error:
            print(error.__str__())
if __name__ == "__main__":
    try:
        app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
        grabber = KeyGrabber()
        grabber.show()
        sys.exit(app.exec_())
    except Exception as error:
        print(str(error))
```

and here's the code for the side widget:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

# Form implementation generated from reading ui file 'help.ui'
#
# Created by: PyQt5 UI code generator 5.15.9
#
# WARNING: Any manual changes made to this file will be lost when pyuic5 is
# run again.  Do not edit this file unless you know what you are doing.


from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
import sys

class Ui_Form(object):
    def setupUi(self, Form):
        Form.setObjectName("Form")
        Form.resize(273, 376)
        self.name_label = QtWidgets.QLabel(Form)
        self.name_label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 10, 47, 13))
        self.name_label.setObjectName("name_label")
        self.name_input = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(Form)
        self.name_input.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 30, 201, 21))
        self.name_input.setObjectName("name_input")
        self.issue_label = QtWidgets.QLabel(Form)
        self.issue_label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 60, 91, 16))
        self.issue_label.setObjectName("issue_label")
        self.issue_input = QtWidgets.QTextEdit(Form)
        self.issue_input.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 80, 241, 111))
        self.issue_input.setObjectName("issue_input")
        self.email_label = QtWidgets.QLabel(Form)
        self.email_label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 200, 201, 16))
        self.email_label.setObjectName("email_label")
        self.email_input = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(Form)
        self.email_input.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 220, 201, 21))
        self.email_input.setObjectName("email_input")
        self.send = QtWidgets.QPushButton(Form)
        self.send.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 290, 121, 51))
        self.send.setObjectName("send")
        self.pushButton_2 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(Form)
        self.pushButton_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(150, 290, 121, 51))
        self.pushButton_2.setObjectName("pushButton_2")

        self.retranslateUi(Form)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Form)

    def retranslateUi(self, Form):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        Form.setWindowTitle(_translate("Form", "Form"))
        self.name_label.setText(_translate("Form", "name"))
        self.issue_label.setText(_translate("Form", "describe the issue:"))
        self.email_label.setText(_translate("Form", "your email (not required):"))
        self.send.setText(_translate("Form", "send"))
        self.pushButton_2.setText(_translate("Form", "cancel"))
        self.pushButton_2.clicked.connect(self.close)
    def close(self):
        sys.exit(0)

def main(argv):
    try:
        app = QtWidgets.QApplication(argv)
        Form = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        ui = Ui_Form()
        ui.setupUi(Form)
        Form.show()
    except Exception as error:
        print(error.__str__())
```

Comment: Create another subclass of QWidget and follow the instructions about [using Designer](//www.riverbankcomputing.com/static/Docs/PyQt5/designer.html) (possibly using the multiple inheritance method), then in `show_widget` do something like `self.helpWidget = MyHelpWidget()` and `self.helpWidget.show()`. Note: pyuic files should **never** be edited, and only *one* QApplication instance can every exist and be running.

Answer (score 0):

this was answered by musicamante. but  i wanted to write it in code form, so here it is:

1. import the side widget into the main widget
2. connect the class to a class in the current file that inherits from the original class:

```
import help
class helpUI(help.Ui_Form, QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)
```

3. turn the class into an object:

```
helpUIclass = HelpUI()
```

and that's it! the new widget can now be shown and used like any other widget

Comment: Notes: 1. remove `self.retranslateUi(self)` as it's redundant (it's already called by `setupUi()`); 2. it's important that the new instance has a persistent reference, otherwise it will be garbage collected as soon as the function that creates it returns (unless the widget is parented to another widget, for instance by adding it to a layout); 3. it's good practice to always include a keyworded `parent=None` argument in the `__init__` and call the super with that (or eventually use the common `*args, **kwargs` syntax for both the `def` and the `super()` call).

Comment: thanks!, i won't change the answer since both of those issues don't really effect anything, but i did do that in the actual project

Comment: Remember that answers are not useful only to those who ask the question, but to anybody else. If somebody looks for a problem similar to yours and finds your answer, they would assume that your code is perfectly fine and that's how things should be done, which is not the case: besides the `parent` aspect, the first two points *are* important.

Comment: i guess you're right, so i'l change it